# Why using volcano plots in biostatistics?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, biostatistics

In biology, it seems common to use a "volcano plot".
Typically, it displays $-log_{10}(\text{p-value})$ in function of the fold-change (=difference of means between two biological conditions). See for instance :
http://bioinformatics.knowledgeblog.org/2011/06/21/volcano-plots-of-microarray-data/

The used p-values correspond to t-tests testing the nullity of the fold-change:
$H_0 "\text{Fold-Change }=0"$ against $H_1 "\text{Fold-Change}\neq 0"$.

Biologists often put a threshold on the p-values and others on the fold-changes to find individuals with significantly non-null and sufficiently high fold-changes.

This approach leaves me skeptical about the benefits of using a volcano plot because thresholding directly on the fold change does not take into account the individual variances.

Why they did not test directly:

$H_0: "|\text{Fold-Change}|< t"$ against $H_1 "|\text{Fold-Change}|> t"$

where $t$ is a threshold on the fold-changes. In such a case, the p-values will be different for each $t$, and a different p-value threshold can be found for each $t$ using multiple testing procedures. As a result, we will get different  volcano plots, one for each $t$...

It seems a more rigorous approach, does not it? Can someone explain the differences between these approaches and if there is a real benefit to proceed like this?

Do you know R packages allowing to do such unusual volcano plots?

Thanks.